# Why my code runs to infinite loop when I input a non integer from scanf?

Tags: c++, scanf, eof

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

#define ll long long

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ll n;
    while(scanf("%lld",&n) != EOF) 
    {
        printf("hello\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// When i input a non integer, the loop runs infinitely, which i think it should not. Can someone please explain?

Comment: `scanf` will not consume anything from the input stream if it fails to parse and `EOF` is not returned in that case -> your loop constantly tries to parse the input, fails to do it (returns 0) and just repeats the `scanf` on the same input

Comment: @UnholySheep thnxx

Comment: The dupe is a C question but it is the same problem (scanf having the same behaviour in both languages)